# Need email passed to Redirect URI after Google api Authenticates

Tags: php, redirect, oauth-2.0, google-api, single-sign-on

So I have this SSO process that is currently working and Authenticating the user but the redirect URI needs the clients email passed to it.

I first hit this function when someone clicks on google sign on:

```
 public function google_signon_login() {
        helper('google');
        $scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
        authenticate($scopes, '/users/google_signon_redirect');
        
    }
```

Then it goes to the auth function:

```
function authenticate($scopes, $redirectUri) {
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("hidden");
    $client->setDeveloperKey(getenv('GOOGLE_API_KEY'));
    $client->setClientId(getenv('GOOGLE_API_ID'));
    $client->setClientSecret(getenv('GOOGLE_API_SECRET'));
    $client->setRedirectUri(site_url($redirectUri));
    foreach($scopes as $scope) {
        $client->addScope($scope);
    }

    try {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['google_access_token'])) {
            if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
                $_SESSION['google_access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
            } else {
                $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
                header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            //If access token already set, check to make sure it contains all requested scopes
            foreach($scopes as $scope) {
                if(!str_contains($_SESSION['google_access_token']['scope'], $scope)) {
                    if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
                        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
                        $_SESSION['google_access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
                    } else {
                        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
                        header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
    
}
```

This all works and authenticates the user but when it redirects to "/users/google_signon_redirect" I need the email to log them in.

I've read something about a state variable but I don't get how that would work because I don't technically have the users email until after they authenticate so it seems like there's one more step that should be here but I'm not clear?

Comment: you have an access token get the email from the user info end point or if there is an id token it should be in teh claims.

Comment: Ok so the access token which is a jwt token that you can extract data from.  I think I've done that before.  When I do that is there some other step to get it to go to the redirect URI or do I just need to make a session and save the email like that?

Comment: The redirect uri is used by the authorization server to know where to return the authorization code your application.    Im not sure why you think you need it for anything

Comment: I need the email of user that just authenticated.  If I can extract that from a access token ok, but then after I go to the redirect how can I access this token?  I did a var_dump in the function it redirects to but no access token was in the session data?  even though you see I attempt to set it in the auth function.

Comment: but your not using authencation.  your using authorization.  there is a difference.

Comment: ok I figured it out.  I needed to call the google api again in my redirect as there's a code there where I can call to extract data.  If you want to make an answer I'll give it to you as talking through this with you helped me